# I can't move a UserControl containing full-size ElementHost in the Windows Forms designer?

Tags: wpf, winforms, windows-forms-designer, elementhost

I have an ElementHost in a Windows Forms UserControl that is sized to the full width/height of the Windows Forms UserControl. The UserControl is on a Form...but I can't move the UserControl or select it in the Designer, because the Child of the ElementHost steals focus whenever I mouse over/click the UserControl in the Designer.

How can I prevent this from happening at Design time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did the following:

```
        if (LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime)
        {
            host.Enabled = false;
        }
```

which now allows me to drag and resize the UserControl on the parent.